# How to factor fold status with scrollbind?

Tags: folding, scrolling

I'd like two scroll bound windows to factor in fold status when scrolling the other window. For example if a fold is closed, the other window would be scrolled by only 1 line rather than the size of the fold.

From what I've read on `scrollbind`, and `scrollbindoptions` this does not appear to be supported out of the box. I'm hoping there is some clever state I can track in a plugin to manage the offsets in a plugin.  This may mean turning `scrollbind` off and somehow manually updating scroll position in the second window.  Solution need only work for two vertically split windows.

Visual example of two windows with `scrollbind` set:
State before scrolling:
[image: example of state before scrolling]

State after scrolling past collapsed fold:
[image: current state after scrolling past a collapsed fold]

Desired state after scrolling past collapsed fold:
[image: desired state after scrolling past collapsed fold]

Comment: This seems like a bug. (I have not tested it, so can't say if it's reproducible.)